# xltabular: Help me for the table

Tags: xltabular

I created this table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=.8cm,bindingoffset=0mm,top=.75cm,includefoot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\parindent0mm

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{9.7cm}
%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\scriptsize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lcX}
\multicolumn{3}{X}{LAMPIRAN PERATURAN MENTERI NEGARA\newline PENDAYAGUNAAN APARATUR NEGARA DAN REFORMASI BIROKRASI} \\
NOMOR &:& 16 TAHUN 2009\\
TANGGAL &:& 10 November 2009\\
\end{xltabular}
\end{minipage}}
\bigbreak%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\bfseries DAFTAR USUL  \\                                               
PENETAPAN ANGKA KREDIT GURU\\
\begin{tabular}{lcl}                                    
NOMOR &:& \makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}\\
\end{tabular}       
\end{center}
\medbreak\scriptsize%--------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|c|c|c|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Instansi: SMK Negeri 2 Sumbawa Besar}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{3}{r}{Masa penilaian: Juli 2008 s.d. Desember 2010}  \\ \hline
\bfseries NO.& \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\bfseries KETERANGAN PERORANGAN}\\\hline
1 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Nama} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\bfseries SULAEMAN, S.Pd.}\\\hline
2 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{NIP} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{196802151991011001}\\\hline
3 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{NUPTK} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{3547746648200062}\\\hline
4 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Nomor Seri Kartu Pegawai} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{E 970872}\\\hline
5 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Tempat  dan Tanggal Lahir} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Majalengka, 15 Februari 1968}\\\hline
6 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jenis Kelamin} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Laki-laki}\\\hline
7 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Pendidikan yang Diperhitungkan Angka Kreditnya} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{S1/Akta IV}\\\hline
8 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Pangkat/Golongan Ruang/TMT} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{IV/a/1 Oktober 2007}\\\hline
9 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jabatan} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Guru Madya}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Masa Kerja Golongan}} & Lama & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{ }\\\cline{7-13}
 & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} & Baru & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{ }\\\hline
11 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jenis Guru} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Guru Mata Pelajaran}\\\hline
12 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Unit Kerja} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{SMK Negeri 2 Sumbawa Besar}\\\hline
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\bfseries UNSUR YANG DINILAI}\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\bfseries NO.} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\bfseries UNSUR, SUB UNSUR, DAN BUTIR KEGIATAN}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries ANGKA KREDIT MENURUT}\\\cline{8-13}
& \multicolumn{6}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries INSTANSI PENGUSUL} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries TIM PENILAI}\\\cline{8-13}
&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries LAMA}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries BARU}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries JUMLAH} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries LAMA} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries BARU} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries JUMLAH}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries 1}&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 3} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 4}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 5}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 6}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 7}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 8}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries I}&\multicolumn{6}{l|}{\bfseries UNSUR UTAMA}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 1} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PENDIDIKAN}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Mengikuti pendidikan dan memperoleh gelar/ijazah/akta}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Doktor (S3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Magister (S2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 3. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Sarjana (S1)/Diploma IV}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{3-13}
& & B. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Mengikuti pelatihan prajabatan}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Pelatihan prajabatan fungsional bagi guru calon pegawai negeri sipil/program induksi}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 2} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PEMBELAJARAN/BIMBINGAN DAN TUGAS TERTENTU}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan proses pembelajaran}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Merencanakan dan melaksanakan pembelajaran,   mengevaluasi dan menilai hasil pembelajaran, menganalisis hasil pembelajaran,  melaksanakan tindak lanjut hasil penilaian}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{3-13}
& & B. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan proses bimbingan}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Merencanakan dan melaksanakan pembimbingan,   mengevaluasi dan menilai hasil bimbingan, menganalisis hasil bimbingan,  melaksanakan tindak lanjut hasil pembimbingan}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{3-13}
& & C. & \multicolumn{4}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Melaksanakan tugas lain yang relevan dengan fungsi  sekolah/madrasah}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi Kepala Sekolah/Madrasah per tahun}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi Wakil Kepala Sekolah/Madrasah per tahun}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 3. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi ketua program keahlian/program studi atau yang sejenisnya}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 4. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi  kepala perpustakaan}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 5. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi kepala laboratorium, bengkel, unit produksi atau yang sejenisnya}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 6. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi pembimbing khusus pada satuan pendidikan   yang menyelenggarakan pendidikan inklusi, pendidikan terpadu atau yang  sejenisnya}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 7. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi wali kelas}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 8. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menyusun kurikulum pada satuan pendidikannya}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 9. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi pengawas penilaian dan evaluasi terhadap  proses dan hasil belajar}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 10. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Membimbing guru pemula dalam program induksi}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 11. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Membimbing siswa dalam kegiatan ekstrakurikuler}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 12. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi pembimbing pada penyusunan publikasi ilmiah dan karya inovatif}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 13. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Melaksanakan pembimbingan pada kelas yang menjadi   tanggung jawabnya (khusus Guru Kelas)}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries } &\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\bfseries JUMLAH}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 3} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PENGEMBANGAN KEPROFESIAN BERKELANJUTAN}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan pengembangan diri}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Mengikuti diklat fungsional}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{a.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya lebih dari 960 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{b.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya antara 641 s.d. 960 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{c.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya antara 481 s.d. 640 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{d.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya antara 181 s.d. 480 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{e.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya antara 81 s.d. 180 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{f.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lamanya antara 30 s.d. 80 jam}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Kegiatan kolektif guru yang meningkatkan kompetensi dan/atau keprofesian guru}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-13}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{a.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Lokakarya atau kegiatan bersama (seperti kelompok kerja guru) untuk penyusunan perangkat kurikulum dan/atau pembelajaran}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{b.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Keikutsertaan pada kegiatan ilmiah (seminar, kologium dan diskusi panel)}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1)} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi pembahas pada kegiatan ilmiah}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{6-13}
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2)} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Menjadi peserta pada kegiatan ilmiah}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

The result looks normal up to the line 96.
[image]
But when continued by

```
& & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{c.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}X|}{Kegiatan kolektif lainnya yang sesuai dengan tugas dan kewajiban guru}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{5-13}
```

on line 97, the table looks weird.
[image]
What is wrong?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem better?

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I have edited.

Comment: The documentation of the `tabularx` package states:  "*Do not use \multicolumn entries which cross any X column."*  If your code, you use multiple `\multicolumn` commands crossing various `X` type columns, so I'm not too surprised that you get an unexpected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remark "Do not use \multicolumn entries which cross any X column." in the `tabularx` documentation applies to the case where you use constructs like `>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X` (section 4.3). As far as I understand it is not applicable in general.

However, what I found is happening in your case is that the many uses of `\multicolumn` in effect kill the calculation of the `X` column width. The package can only calculate this if there is enough flexibility in these `X` columns to make it possible to adjust them. There are several `X` columns whose widths get overridden because some `\multicolumn` makes it effectively bigger than what the system has calculated. This means that fewer and fewer columns are left that still have some flexibility, and then line 96 finally takes the last flexibility away. It then gives the `X` columns a width of 0. You can check this with the command `\tracingtabularx` and look in the log file.

So I propose a different solution.  It doesn't make sense to have a `X` column if that will be overridden anyway.

1. The last 6 columns can be given a fixed width, say about 1/20 of `\textwidth`, with centered text (`wc` format).
2. The first six columns if used separately have small items like a number. So these can be given a fixed small width, and have their text entered. This gets rid of a lot of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` constructs. Otherwise they are part of a `\multicolumn`. Giving them a known width makes it possible to calculate the widths of the `\multicolumn`s.
3. There are a lot of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` constructs. I think this doesn't make sense and they can be replaced by an empty cell.
4. This leaves column 7 as the only `X` column. I pick up its width in the table's preamble argument to use in the `\multicolumn`s.
5. I define new column types `I` (for the first 6 columns), `J` (`\multicolumn{4}` column 4-7), `K` (`\multicolumn{3}` column 5-7), `L` (`\multicolumn{2}` column 6-7) and `M` (for the last 6 columns).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=.8cm,bindingoffset=0mm,top=.75cm,includefoot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\tracingtabularx
\parindent0mm

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{9.7cm}
%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\scriptsize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lcX}
\multicolumn{3}{X}{LAMPIRAN PERATURAN MENTERI NEGARA\newline PENDAYAGUNAAN APARATUR NEGARA DAN REFORMASI BIROKRASI} \\
NOMOR &:& 16 TAHUN 2009\\
TANGGAL &:& 10 November 2009\\
\end{xltabular}
\end{minipage}}
\bigbreak%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\bfseries DAFTAR USUL  \\                                               
PENETAPAN ANGKA KREDIT GURU\\
\begin{tabular}{lcl}                                    
NOMOR &:& \makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}\\
\end{tabular}       
\end{center}
\medbreak\scriptsize%--------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% Length variables for column widths
\newlength\LX % width of X column (column 7)
% It seems I need some extra space for the \multicolumns, I don't know
% why, but it looks better this way. I got it by trial and error.
\newcommand{\LY}{1cm} % extra space for \multicolumns
\newlength\LI % width of columns 1-6
\setlength\LI{0.02\textwidth}
\newlength\LM % width of column 8-13
\setlength\LM{0.05\textwidth}

\newcolumntype{I}{wc{\LI}} % for columns 1-6
\newcolumntype{J}{p{\dimexpr 3\LI+\LX+3\tabcolsep+\LY}} % for \multicolumn{4}{column 4,5,6,7}
\newcolumntype{K}{p{\dimexpr 2\LI+\LX+2\tabcolsep+\LY}} % for \multicolumn{3}{column 5,6,7}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{\dimexpr \LI+\LX+\tabcolsep+\LY}} % for \multicolumn{2}{column 6,7}
\newcolumntype{M}{wc{\LM}} % for columns 8-13

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{| I | I | I | I | I | I | >{\global\LX=\hsize\raggedright}X | M | M | M | M | M | M |}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Instansi: SMK Negeri 2 Sumbawa Besar} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{Masa penilaian: Juli 2008 s.d. Desember 2010}  \\ \hline
\bfseries NO.& \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\bfseries KETERANGAN PERORANGAN}\\\hline
1 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Nama} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{\bfseries SULAEMAN, S.Pd.}\\\hline
2 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{NIP} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{196802151991011001}\\\hline
3 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{NUPTK} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{3547746648200062}\\\hline
4 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Nomor Seri Kartu Pegawai} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{E 970872}\\\hline
5 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Tempat  dan Tanggal Lahir} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Majalengka, 15 Februari 1968}\\\hline
6 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jenis Kelamin} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Laki-laki}\\\hline
7 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Pendidikan yang Diperhitungkan Angka Kreditnya} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{S1/Akta IV}\\\hline
8 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Pangkat/Golongan Ruang/TMT} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{IV/a/1 Oktober 2007}\\\hline
9 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jabatan} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Guru Madya}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Masa Kerja Golongan}} & Lama & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{ }\\\cline{7-13}
 & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} & Baru & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{ }\\\hline
11 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Jenis Guru} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Guru Mata Pelajaran}\\\hline
12 & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Unit Kerja} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{SMK Negeri 2 Sumbawa Besar}\\\hline
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\bfseries UNSUR YANG DINILAI}\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\bfseries NO.} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\bfseries UNSUR, SUB UNSUR, DAN BUTIR KEGIATAN}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries ANGKA KREDIT MENURUT}\\\cline{8-13}
& \multicolumn{6}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries INSTANSI PENGUSUL} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries TIM PENILAI}\\\cline{8-13}
&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{}&{\bfseries LAMA}&{\bfseries BARU}& {\bfseries JUMLAH} & {\bfseries LAMA} & {\bfseries BARU} & {\bfseries JUMLAH}\\\hline
{\bfseries 1}&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries 2}&{\bfseries 3} &{\bfseries 4}&{\bfseries 5}&{\bfseries 6}&{\bfseries 7}&{\bfseries 8}\\\hline
{\bfseries I}&\multicolumn{6}{l|}{\bfseries UNSUR UTAMA}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
&{\bfseries 1} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PENDIDIKAN}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Mengikuti pendidikan dan memperoleh gelar/ijazah/akta}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Doktor (S3)}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Magister (S2)}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 3. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Sarjana (S1)/Diploma IV}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{3-13}
& & B. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Mengikuti pelatihan prajabatan}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Pelatihan prajabatan fungsional bagi guru calon pegawai negeri sipil/program induksi}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
&{\bfseries 2} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PEMBELAJARAN/BIMBINGAN DAN TUGAS TERTENTU}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan proses pembelajaran}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Merencanakan dan melaksanakan pembelajaran,   mengevaluasi dan menilai hasil pembelajaran, menganalisis hasil pembelajaran,  melaksanakan tindak lanjut hasil penilaian}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{3-13}
& & B. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan proses bimbingan}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & - & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Merencanakan dan melaksanakan pembimbingan,   mengevaluasi dan menilai hasil bimbingan, menganalisis hasil bimbingan,  melaksanakan tindak lanjut hasil pembimbingan}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{3-13}
& & C. & \multicolumn{4}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}J|}{Melaksanakan tugas lain yang relevan dengan fungsi  sekolah/madrasah}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi Kepala Sekolah/Madrasah per tahun}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi Wakil Kepala Sekolah/Madrasah per tahun}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 3. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Menjadi ketua program keahlian/program studi atau yang sejenisnya}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 4. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi  kepala perpustakaan}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 5. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Menjadi kepala laboratorium, bengkel, unit produksi atau yang sejenisnya}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 6. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Menjadi pembimbing khusus pada satuan pendidikan   yang menyelenggarakan pendidikan inklusi, pendidikan terpadu atau yang  sejenisnya}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 7. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menjadi wali kelas}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 8. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Menyusun kurikulum pada satuan pendidikannya}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 9. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Menjadi pengawas penilaian dan evaluasi terhadap  proses dan hasil belajar}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 10. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Membimbing guru pemula dalam program induksi}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 11. & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Membimbing siswa dalam kegiatan ekstrakurikuler}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 12. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Menjadi pembimbing pada penyusunan publikasi ilmiah dan karya inovatif}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 13. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Melaksanakan pembimbingan pada kelas yang menjadi   tanggung jawabnya (khusus Guru Kelas)}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
&{\bfseries } &\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\bfseries JUMLAH}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
&{\bfseries 3} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{\bfseries PENGEMBANGAN KEPROFESIAN BERKELANJUTAN}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{2-13}
& & A. & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Melaksanakan pengembangan diri}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 1. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Mengikuti diklat fungsional}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & &  & {a.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya lebih dari 960 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & {b.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya antara 641 s.d. 960 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & {c.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya antara 481 s.d. 640 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & {d.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya antara 181 s.d. 480 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & &  & {e.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya antara 81 s.d. 180 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & & & {f.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lamanya antara 30 s.d. 80 jam}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & 2. & \multicolumn{3}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}K|}{Kegiatan kolektif guru yang meningkatkan kompetensi dan/atau keprofesian guru}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{4-13}
& & & & {a.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Lokakarya atau kegiatan bersama (seperti kelompok kerja guru) untuk penyusunan perangkat kurikulum dan/atau pembelajaran}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & & & {b.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Keikutsertaan pada kegiatan ilmiah (seminar, kologium dan diskusi panel)}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
& & & &    & {1)} & {Menjadi pembahas pada kegiatan ilmiah}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{6-13}
& & & &    & {2)} & {Menjadi peserta pada kegiatan ilmiah}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
  & & & & {c.} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\arraybackslash\raggedright}L|}{Kegiatan kolektif lainnya yang sesuai dengan tugas dan kewajiban guru}&   &  &  &  &  &  \\\cline{5-13}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: This is a lesson for me. Thank you for your help.